# Webview error using Readium 2 for android

Tags: android, epub, readiumjs

I'm trying to use readium 2 library for my android project. I cloned [r2-workspace-kotlin](https://github.com/readium/r2-workspace-kotlin) repo. I launched the app on some of my test devices. I noticed that on one device the app is unable to render some pages. Instead of what should be a page of the book I get a page saying *Webpage not available*. The device is running android 7.1.2 but it's not related to android version as I tested the app on emulator running the same version and it worked. Anyone has any ideas how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: do you know what `127.0.0.1` is?

Comment: `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` is address used to establish an IP connection to the same machine or computer being used by the end-user.

Comment: right, it is `the same device`, so when you are trying to access it **from the phone**, it will refer **to the same device** - **the phone**. Are you sure you are running the web server on the same device (the phone)?

Comment: I don't have a deep understanding of how readium library works. What I see is that it renders some pages correctly but fails to render other pages and it happens on the same book. I was hoping for an answer from someone who has dealt with this problem and found a solution.

Comment: the problem is that you somehow are trying to open the `127.0.0.1:xxx/xxx` url in your webView. This sends the request to **the same machine**, which means to the Android phone itself. And as your Android phone does not run the web server on port `45685`, it will not work. I don't think that somebody can understand why you request this url without you showing any code.